# Call asp.net web service in android

Tags: android

I have create an web service in asp.net.

now i want to call that web service in android.

Please Help me.

I need a correct code with the little bit of description so that I can understand the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to try it for your self and if you get stuck, then you ask a question here

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add [ksoap](http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.5.7/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar) to your project.

And then you just need to follow [this](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks)

I was looking for the same resource, and I used ksoap. It works like a charm. I recommend you to use it.

Please let me know if you have more doubts, I'll be glad to help you.

Thanks.

Comment: That links points to a old release. Use the latest .. there are lots of fixes in since 2.2

Answer (score 0):

If it is a SOAP web service you probably want to use [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). There is lots of links and documentation on the site as well as a mailinglist on which myself and other try to help out.

Comment: yes i have tried ksoap2 api and run a sample code but m getting an error

Comment: ask on the mailing list or in a separate question on stackoverflow about it

Comment: when i run my code into emulator it gives me this error :
    “The application MyPro(process com.android.mypro) has stopped unexpectedly please try agan.

Comment: well.. you need to do the webservice call in a asynctask or so and provide more detail... post a stack trace or whatever in a separate question.. and accept an answer on this one..

Comment: what do you mean by asyntask ?

what is Stack Trace .?

Comment: Well, you must see what is it showing in LogCat. Stacktrace will be printed in logcat. To see the log cat go to: Window > Show View > Other > Logcat. Let that perspective opened while runing your app, and the error will appear in red color. Copy it and paste in your question.